# How to resolve dll UnsatisfiedLinkError when using JNA 4.2.0 with Java 6 on Windows 7.1?

Tags: java, dll, jna, 32-bit, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I'm using version 4.2.0 of the JNA libraries from here: https://github.com/java-native-access/jna.

My application works absolutely fine on Java 7 & 8 32-bit on a 64-bit Windows 7.1 machine.

When I try to load it using Java 6 32-bit, I get this error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeMainClass(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\jna-205523658\jna1343790277438028829.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
 at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:851)
 at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:826)
 at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:140)
 at com.sun.jna.Pointer.<clinit>(Pointer.java:41)
 at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinReg$HKEY.<init>(WinReg.java:32)
 at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinReg.<clinit>(WinReg.java:61)
```

Is this an incompatibility issue between 32-bit Java 6 on a 64-bit OS? Is there anything I can do about it?

My problem is that I need to deploy my app to a wide user base all with different permutations of Java 32-bit on different Windows operating systems.

Comment: Can you run `java -jar jna.jar` under Java 6 32-bit?

Comment: java -jar jna-4.2.0.jar
    Java Native Access (JNA) API Version 4
    Version: 4.2.0 (b0)
    Native: 4.0.1 (1a6047467b59e8748f975e03016ce3d9)
    Prefix: win32-x86-64

Comment: That's the 64-bit version.  What about the 32-bit version?